# Reverse the letter case in a string using List

Tags: c#, string, list

I don't understand where is my mistake, and would appreciate help. I would like to reverse the letter case in a string and return reversed chars to the List using `List.Add()` method.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

public class Program 
{
    public static string ReverseCase(string str) 
    {
            List<char> result = new List<char>();
            foreach(char pew in str){
                char.IsUpper(pew) ? result.Add(Char.ToLower(pew)):result.Add(Char.ToUpper(pew));
            }
            return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to reverse a string? And put the char into an array?

Comment: You can't call a method inside the branches of a ternary operator.  Put the ternary operator _inside_ the call to `result.Add()`.  Also, always be sure to include in your question any errors reported by the compiler.  Finally, what you call "reverse" I think would be more commonly called "invert".

Comment: @BACON to be more precise, the operands of `?:` cannot be `void` (methods which return a value do, of course, work).

Comment: @Moira Aha, yes, of course.  Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @BACON thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Get the `char` first and add it to the list, like this approach :

```
public static string ReverseCase(string str)
{
    List<char> result = new List<char>();
    foreach (char pew in str)
    {
        result.Add(char.IsUpper(pew) ? char.ToLower(pew) : char.ToUpper(pew));
    }
    return new string(result.ToArray());
}
```

Note that, `result.ToString()` can't convert list of  `char` to `string`.

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: `result.Add(char.IsUpper(pew) ? Char.ToLower(pew) : Char.ToUpper(pew));` and returning it as a `new string(result.ToArray());` worked perfectly for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here - first, the usage of the `?` operator - you can't use code blocks there, just values. So instead of using it with two `Add` calls, you can use it to get the correct value within an `Add` call.

Second, calling `ToString()` on a List won't do what you expect it to do. You could, however, join the characters in the list to get a string:

```
public static string ReverseCase(string str) 
{
        List<char> result = new List<char>();
        foreach(char pew in str){
            result.Add(char.IsUpper(pew) ? Char.ToLower(pew) : Char.ToUpper(pew));
        }
        return String.Join("", result);
}
```